# WebFormsMVP Model in OnInit event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webformsmvp

I'm trying to add dynamic controls based on model in OnInit method but i get the `"The Model property is currently null, however it should have been automatically initialized by the presenter. This most likely indicates that no presenter was bound to the control. Check your presenter bindings."` error. But if i add controls in OnLoad they are not working right - events are not fired.

Also from what i see presenter binding is occuring in InitComplete event

Code:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnInit(e);

        this.OnLoadTitle();

        foreach (var platform in Model.Title.Platforms)
        {
            var tab = CreateTabForPlatform(platform);
            this.TabView.Tabs.Add(tab);
        }
    }
```

How can i get around this issue. Thank you/

Comment: On OnInit event , your Model did not Initialized. You should put your code in your OnLoad event. Let's see if it works.

Comment: It works, control gets created BUT control doesnt behave correctly, it doesn't fire events